# Simple C app gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

C has never been a great force of mine, but I decided to give it a go. The following is my code, but when run, it gives a segmentation fault (core dumped).

Basically what I want, is to check if the folder is empty (mtp device mounted in it), and if it is empty, run the mount command, and if not, run the other command.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <libnotify/notify.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main ()
{
  int n = 0;
  struct dirent *d;
  const char *dir_path="~/Nexus";
  DIR *dir = opendir(dir_path);
      while ((d = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if(++n > 2)
          break;
      }
      closedir(dir);
      if (n <= 2) //Directory Empty
    {
    notify_init ("Galaxy Nexus mounter");
    NotifyNotification * Mount = notify_notification_new ("Galaxy Nexus", "Mounted at ~/Nexus", "/home/tristan202/bin/test/android_on.png");
    system("jmtpfs ~/Nexus");
    notify_notification_show (Mount, NULL);
    }
      else
    {
    notify_init ("Galaxy Nexus mounter");
    NotifyNotification * uMount = notify_notification_new ("Galaxy Nexus", "Unmounted", "/home/tristan202/bin/test/android_off.png");
    system("fusermount -u ~/Nexus");
    notify_notification_show (uMount, NULL);
    }
    }
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <libnotify/notify.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main ()
{
  int n = 0;
  struct dirent *d;
  const char *dir_path="/home/tristan202/Nexus";
  DIR *dir = opendir(dir_path);
      while ((d = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if(++n > 2)
          break;
      }
      closedir(dir);
      if (n <= 2) //Directory Empty
    {
    notify_init ("Galaxy Nexus mounter");
    NotifyNotification * Mount = notify_notification_new ("Galaxy Nexus", "Mounted at ~/Nexus", "/home/tristan202/bin/test/android_on.png");
    system("jmtpfs ~/Nexus");
    notify_notification_show (Mount, NULL);
    }
      else
    {
    notify_init ("Galaxy Nexus mounter");
    NotifyNotification * uMount = notify_notification_new ("Galaxy Nexus", "Unmounted", "/home/tristan202/bin/test/android_off.png");
    system("fusermount -u ~/Nexus");
    notify_notification_show (uMount, NULL);
    }
    }
```

Comment: I would definitely think that it Seg Faults because you neglect to check for current and parent directories. You need to continue when reading the directory and see "." and ".."

Comment: That is why I set 'n' to be over or under 2. Shouldn't that be good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. You don't check for errors.  If `opendir(2)` fails to open the directory and returns `NULL`, you keep going, and passing in `NULL` to `readdir(2)` will likely cause it to segfault.  This is probably failing because...
2. The file system doesn't understand what you mean when you write `"~"`, as in `"~/Nexus"`.  It tries to open a file *literally* named `"~/Nexus"`.  The `~` character has no special meaning in the file system -- it means something to the *shell*.  The shell is the one that performs [tilde expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Tilde-Expansion).  In order to get the file you want, you need to either use the correct full, absolute path or a correct relative path; you can use [`getenv("HOME")`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv) to find your own home directory at runtime.  Note that it's ok to use `~` in the calls to the `system(3)` function, since `system` invokes the shell.
3. `main()` is not declared correctly.  It must return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: I have edited the main post with your suggested changes. For now it works as supposed, but I will keep working on it to make it work on other machines, i.e. use the getenv, instead of what I did.